# Why do we need ident if there is native_id in threading module?

Tags: python

Once you have created a `threading.Thread` object, you can access `.native_id` and `ident` attributes, which, basically, return thread ID. In which situations should I use one instead of another?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for [get_ident()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident) and [get_native_id()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_native_id), the first is assigned by the Python interpreter and is meaningless in terms of OS. The latter, however, is the Thread ID assigned by the kernel.